# Upload Static Files ONLY to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

My intention is to upload just static html file to google app engine. **No servlets, no JSPs.**

I have the following directory structure

```
C:\Users\yccheok\Desktop\sandbox\index.html
C:\Users\yccheok\Desktop\sandbox\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
C:\Users\yccheok\Desktop\sandbox\WEB-INF\web.xml
```

The content of appengine-web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>xiang-qi</application>
    <version>1</version>
</appengine-web-app>
```

The content of web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
</web-app>
```

I use the following command :

```
C:\Users\yccheok\Desktop\sandbox>c:\appengine-java-sdk-1.2.2\bin\appcfg.cmd upda
te .
```

But it just hang there :

```
Reading application configuration data...
2009-09-30 13:43:51.061::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
Beginning server interaction for xiang-qi...
0% Creating staging directory
5% Scanning for jsp files.
20% Scanning files on local disk.
25% Initiating update.
Email: yancheng.cheok@gmail.com
Password for yancheng.cheok@gmail.com:
Email: yancheng.cheok@gmail.com
Password for yancheng.cheok@gmail.com:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify paths to static files - see [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files) for details. If appcfg is just hanging, though, that looks like a separate issue. Are you behind a proxy server of some sort?

Comment: It seems to be my network slowness problem. I try using better internet speed. It works then.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard stories that deploying Java apps is slower than Python apps. You may consider doing it with the Python or Go runtimes (I assume the Go runtime is similar to the Python one). You may check which one of the three suits you better (whether it's fast enough, whether you would prefer editing YAML over XML, what's language you'd use for a future version of the app, etc) and then use it.

I'm not sure if you can have different runtimes on different versions of the app. Should be fun to try.